# Subject control or object control?

Tags: dependency-grammar, subordination, control

In the recent paper “[Universal Dependencies](https://aclanthology.org/2021.cl-2.11/)” by de Larneffe, Manning, Nivre and Zeman, published in *Computational Linguistics* in 2021, page 277 the following example is given:
[image]

and it is said that **xcomp** is used for clausal complements with obligatory subject control.

Could somebody explain me why this is **subject** control and not **object** control?

Isn't this the case where we can write

```
She told Fred_i [PRO_i to take the job]
```

where Fred_i is the object of the control verb to tell, as described in Carnie's *Syntax* textbook, p. 443?

I can hardly believe that a paper by so prestigious people in a so prestigious journal has made such a trivial error… So, most probably, I'm overseeing something. Could somebody please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: It seems to be a synonym for obligatory Equi. Just a different term, and so is xcomp. The way to make a name in linguistics is to make a name in linguistics. All the phenomena have already been discovered; only the names have been changed, to protect the innocent.

Comment: Can you give me a reference for “obligatory Equi”? Thanks in advance ! BTW I love your jeu-de-mots “ The way to make a name in linguistics is to make a name in linguistics.” (you used it also about metonymy in the English Language forum), I will definitely use it and quote you.

Comment: Try [this handout from my Intro Ling class](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: In a complex catenative construction like this, where the subordinate complement clause is an infinitival, the intervening NP is always the syntactic object of the matrix verb (here, *tell") and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause. Note that the object is not a raised one but an ordinary one.

Comment: Right. It's Equi, not Raising. B-configuration.

Comment: After taking a quick look at the source article, the authors are indeed mistaken. The sentence contains object control, clearly. The verb _tell_ is an object control predicate. Note that they are using the UD annotation scheme in the article, which subordinates function words to content words. That sort of approach is not well-motivated linguistically. Tests for constituents identify most (not all!) function words as heads over content words.